# Not able to install istio with helm on my digitalocean kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, digital-ocean, istio

I have downloaded the latest stable release of istio i.e.1.11.4 and am executing the below command inside the root of the istio release folder:

```
helm install istio install/kubernetes/helm/istio --namespace istio-system --set grafana.enabled=True --set kiali.enabled=True
```

When I do, I get the error:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to download "install/kubernetes/helm/istio"
```

My helm version: `version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.7.1"`

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are using some old command to install Istio.

Check out the latest installation docs: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/#installation-steps

Additionally, the addons (grafana, kiali, or prometheus) are not part of Istio anymore and need to be installed separately as shown here:

- Prometheus:
  https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/
- Grafana: https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/grafana/
- Kiali: https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/kiali/